# El Capitan update 10.11.1 stuck at installing update in app store

Tags: mac-appstore, install, software-update, macos

When installing the update for El capitan it got stuck at installing in app store. It has said "Installing - less then a minute" in several hours.

Can I somehow restart or redo the install/update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you are still in App Store; you haven't actually launched the `Install OS X El Capitan` file yet [or it hasn't auto-launched]?

If the installer isn't yet running, you're safe to cancel it.

My App Store download errored at the last second & when I clicked the Update button again it suddenly realised everything was in fact fine.
Check if you have the installer app in your Applications folder. If you do, then it actually downloaded OK & you ought to be able to double-click it to continue.

As always on a major update, make sure your backup is up to date; & as a double safety-net, remove or disconnect your Time Machine drive until you are happy all went well with the update.

Comment: Yes I'm still in app store. I don't tink I was clear enough, El Capitan is already installed on the machine, this is just an update of it.

It's says installing in app store, the mac haven't restart yet which is required for this update, it says. 

Can't seem to find the the update in the application folder but I don't think ever will appear there.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, in which case - reboot, check again. If the same try signing out of App Store then back in again. Worst case scenario you can dig the partial out of its folder & trash it, but see if those work first.

Comment: I restarted the mac before without any luck. But when I did as you said, sign out and the in of app store and the restarted the computer, it worked. Thanks a lot! :)